# Call await within response function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await, response

I'm trying to use the await call inside a `response => {}`
But I'm getting an error on the await that says Expecting new line or semicolon.
I would think that the error is due to the structure of the function, but I'm not sure how to rectify it.

What I'm trying to do is add/update the user's profile Image. When the user clicks on a touchableOpacity thumbnail the `_pickImageHandler()` will be called, if the image is picked and the response is ok, 
it will await call the `uploadImageToStorage` function which will upload the image to Firebase Storage.

If  `uploadImageToStorage` returns true I then want to call the editProfileImage to add the downloadUrl to the user's doc.

```
_pickImageHandler = async () => {
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker({title: "Select Image", maxWidth: 800, maxHeight: 600},

   // I'm assuming I have to somehow adapt the below response line to fix my problem
        response => {
            if (response.didCancel) {
                console.log("User cancelled!");
                if (!response.uri) {
                    this.showToast('User profile image cannot be empty', 'ok', 'warning')
                }
            }
            else if (response.error) {
                //todo look at putting below line into toast message
                console.log("Error", response.error);
            }
            else {
                console.log("pickedImage URI: ", response.uri);
                console.log("pickedImage FileName: ", response.fileName);

                this.setState({
                    //pickedImageUri: response.uri,
                    userProfileImageUrl: response.uri,
                    imageName: response.fileName
                });
               // Im getting the error on the below line 
              // Expecting a new line or semicolon
                let didImageUploadToStorage = await this._uploadImageToStorage(response.uri, response.fileName);

                if (didImageUploadToStorage) {
                    console.log('didImageUploadToStorage', didImageUploadToStorage);
                    this.editUserProfileImage()
                }
                else {
                    console.log('didImageUploadToStorage', didImageUploadToStorage);
                }
            }
        })
};



_uploadImageToStorage = async (uri, fileName) => {
    console.log("uploadImage Triggered!");
    console.log("uri: ", uri);
    console.log("fileName: ", fileName);
    //todo add in another folder after userEvents so it will be userEvents/eventDoc.id/filename

    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(ref);


    await storageRef.put(uri)
        .then(snapshot => {
            console.log("Upload Success!!!!! :) ");
            console.log("downloadUrl: ", snapshot.downloadURL);
            this.setState({
                userProfileImageUrl: snapshot.downloadURL,
            });
            return true
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('FirebaseStorage upload error:', error);
            return false
        });
};



 editUserProfileImage = () => {
    console.log('editUserProfileImage FIRED!');
    console.log('editUserProfileImage text: ', this.state.userProfileImageUrl);

    if (!this.state.userProfileImageUrl.length) {
        this.showToast('Profile image URL cannot be empty', 'OK', 'danger');
        return
    }
    console.log('3 userDocExists: ', this.state.userDocExists);
    if (this.state.userDocExists) {
        console.log('docExists == true');
        this.updateFieldInDB(usersCollectionRef, 'i4Mefea0wUjHW07jEk0W', 'userProfileImageUrl', this.state.userProfileImageUrl)
    }
    else {
        console.log('docExists == false');
        this.setFieldInDB(usersCollectionRef, 'i4Mefea0wUjHW07jEk0W', 'userProfileImageUrl', this.state.userProfileImageUrl)
    }
}
```

Is there a better more efficent way with less function calls to do this.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: can you share some demo using jsfiddle or other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `async` to your function, and then `await` will be recognized as a valid keyword within your function (assuming you're using a browser that supports async functions or are transpiling):

```
async response => {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Jacob Thank you very much, I had already tried putting the async before `response` but I got a load of yellow underlines when I did so, I don't know why, but I'm thinking now I might have spelt async wrong  sorry. the didImageUploadToStorage returns undefined, would you be able to point out where I'm going wrong

Answer (score 0):

To use the `await` operator, you have to use it inside an `async` function. Changing your callback to something like this should do the work.

```
async (response) => {
    // your logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see your code, response should have `async`